# How to add 'hover' to a 'div' style

Tags: javascript, css

How can I use *a:hover* in inline CSS inside the HTML *[style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style)* attribute?

Like the following, but it doesn't work.

```html
<div
    style={{
        "&:hover": {
         background: "#efefef"
         },
    }} >
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with JavaScript? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with JavaScript. For instance, it causes the *default* syntax highlighting to be *weird*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```css
a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

See the full answer [at CodePen](https://codepen.io/charp95/pen/LYQxZrm).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```html
<a href="mypage.html"
   onMouseOver="this.style.color='#FFF'"
   onMouseOut="this.style.color='#000'" >Whatever you have to display</a>
```

You can try this. Using onMouseOver and onMouseOut, this gives the same effect, but it's not efficient for many elements.